# Como detectar que el top del navegador tocó un elemento del HTML cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Cordial saludo.

Estoy estudiando JQuery y tengo una pregunta:

como detectar que se tocó `<p>tocar este elemento</p>` con la parte superior haciendo scroll:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LoQueSeaMi</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH" />
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap JS y dependencias de Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://github.com/felipedelosh/AFE-PORTFOLIO/raw/main/assets/img/banner/banner.jpg" alt="img relleno">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar bg-danger text-white">
    <p class="h2">Esto es un navbar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="h1 text_insert0">$</p>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            $('.text_insert0').append("<p>Texto</p><br>");
        }
    </script>
    <p>tocar este elemento</p>
    <p class="h1 text_insert1">$</p>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            $('.text_insert1').append("<p>Texto</p><br>");
        }
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="footer bg-dark text-white">
    <p class="h1">Esto es el fooer</p>
  </div>
  <!-- core  -->
  <script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    _dh = $(window).scrollTop()/$(document).height();
    //alert(_dh);
    if (_dh > 0.8) {
        //alert(_dh);
    }
  });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Como detectar que la parte superior del navegador toca un elemento del HTML cuando voy bajando por la pagina?

Mockup:

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscas el elemento `<p>tocar este elemento</p>` y capturas su posición vertical en todo el documento (en pixeles), utilizando la función [**`offset().top`**](https://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset):

  ```
  let elementTop = $('p:contains("tocar este elemento")').offset().top;
  ```
- Obtienes la posición actual del scroll vertical con la función [**`scrollTop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop):

  ```
  let scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  ```
- Validamos que si la posición vertical del elemento `p` es menor igual a la posición vertical del scroll. Si cumple, quiere decir que el elemento `p` está en la parte superior de la ventana, ya que `scrollTop` devuelve la posición actual del scroll en `px` desde la parte superior:

  ```
  if (elementTop <= scrollTop) {
    console.log("Elemento <p> detectado.");
  }
  ```
- Los valores se irán actualizando a medida que hagamos scroll, utilizando el evento del `scroll` de jQuery:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      // Resto de código...
    });
  });
  ```

---

### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   let elementTop = $('p:contains("tocar este elemento")').offset().top;
   let scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

   console.log(elementTop);
   console.log(scrollTop);

   if (elementTop <= scrollTop) {
    console.log("Elemento <p> detectado.");
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LoQueSeaMi</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH" />
    <!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Incluir Bootstrap JS y dependencias de Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="row">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://github.com/felipedelosh/AFE-PORTFOLIO/raw/main/assets/img/banner/banner.jpg" alt="img relleno">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar bg-danger text-white">
      <p class="h2">Esto es un navbar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="h1 text_insert0">$</p>
      <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          $('.text_insert0').append("<p>Texto</p><br>");
        }
      </script>
      <p>tocar este elemento</p>
      <p class="h1 text_insert1">$</p>
      <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          $('.text_insert1').append("<p>Texto</p><br>");
        }
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="footer bg-dark text-white">
      <p class="h1">Esto es el fooer</p>
    </div>
    <!-- core  -->
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        _dh = $(window).scrollTop()/$(document).height();
        //alert(_dh);
        if (_dh > 0.8) {
          //alert(_dh);
        }
      });
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la respuesta.